# not able to Import SafeAreaProvider of react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I am doing a watch along project development with the help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvn_HYpix6s&t=4191s

Around at 1:07:00, we are adding react native imports. we are referring https://reactnativeelements.com/docs.

I have added **react-native-safe-area-context** npm package.
and did an import as

```
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```

however doing so, I am getting an error as

> Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name
> RNCSafeAreaProvider at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in
> registerError at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in
> console.error at
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in
> reportException at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19
> in handleException at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
> handleError at
> node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in
> ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0 at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in
> PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13
> in tryCallOne at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in
> _callTimer at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in
> _callImmediatesPass

As per suggestion of few forums I have reinstalled the package but same error.
below is the code snippet I wanted to run.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import {store} from './store'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
   <SafeAreaProvider >
      <HomeScreen/>
   
     </SafeAreaProvider >
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

below is the screenshot of mobile emulator.

[image: Emulator Screenshot of error]

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems react-native-safe-area-context is duplicated.
if you installed @react-native-community/masked-view, it will also install  react-native-safe-area-context as a dependency.
If the 2 version is different, you would get such a issue.
Please uninstall react-native-safe-area-context.
Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110), Add the following line on the `scripts` part, on your `package.json`:

```json
"postinstall":"rm -rf node_modules/expo/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context"
```

If, you're not using expo:

```json
"postinstall":"rm -rf node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context"
```